# What is a martingale $(X_n)$ index by the finite set $(0,1,...,N)$?

Tags: probability, definition

In the book of Yor and Revuz : "Continuous martingale and Brownian motion" third edition, proposition 1.5 page 53 : it's written : If $(X_n)$ is an integrable submartingale indexed by the finite set $(0,1,...,N)$... what does it mean exactly ? First $(0,1,...,N)$ is not really a set, so what does he mean by that ?

Comment: If he said $\{0,1,\dots,N\}$ would you be OK with the definition?

Comment: @GEdgar: If so, would it be just $(X_n)=(X_n)_{n=1,...,N}$ ?

Comment: You missed the index $0$ in there.

Comment: @GEdgar yes, I mean $(X_n)_{n=0,...,N}$... but how can this be a martingale ? For example $\mathbb E[X_m\mid \mathcal F_n]=X_n$ is still true if the set is finite ?

Comment: Exactly: $\mathbb E[X_m\mid \mathcal F_n]=X_n$ whenever $m \ge n$.

Comment: @GEdgar : So at the end we just mean $(X_n)_{n=0,...,N}$ ? But why using the notation $(0,...,N)$ for $\{0,...,N\}$ ? And martingale $(X_n)$ for finite numbers $n$ doesn't look strange ?